# Realloc() returning NULL when memory is available - C

Tags: c, directory, realloc

- OS:Windows Vista(x86)
- Compiler: Code::Blocks

I am currently writing a program that opens a specified directory and reads the contents of it. Rather than using printf() to display the file names immediately after they are found. I hold them in memory and display them later. I use the following if statement to trigger memory reallocation. I have also included the declarations of relevant variables.

```
//Represents what the new index will be after the current file name is added
//to 'stack.ptr'
#define NEW_INDEX (stack.index+(strlen(ptr_dirent->d_name)))

//Contains the pointer that points to the directory's contents 'stack.ptr',
//the size of 'stack.ptr' which is 'stack.size', and the current index
//'stack.index'
struct stack
{
  int index;
  char *ptr;
  int size;
};struct stack stack;

//Sets the index to 0 and allocates 256 bytes of memory for 'stack.ptr'
stack.index = 0; stack.size = 256;
stack.ptr = malloc(sizeof(char)*stack.size);

if(NEW_INDEX > stack.size)
{
  char *temp; stack.size *= 2;
  temp = realloc(stack.ptr, sizeof(char)*stack.size);
  if (temp == NULL)
  {
    printf("ERROR: %i Bytes of memory could not be allocated.\n", stack.size);
    free(stack.ptr); closedir(dirp); return '\000';
  }
  else {stack.ptr = temp;}
}
```

The program works perfectly until I set the initial value of 'stack.size'(which is the array size) to 2 rather than 256 (so that the program HAS to reallocate memory). My program crashed because realloc() returned NULL but I had plenty of memory available. I know that realloc() did work a couple of times because
'stack.size' was 16 when it crashed ('stack.size' is doubled every time memory is reallocated). I tried setting 'stack.size' to a couple of different values and I found that setting 'stack.size' to 1 or 2 causes a crash and it always happens when 'stack.size' reaches 16. Can anyone explain this to me? I am worried that even if I set 'stack.size' to 256 my program may crash if a directory is large enough to trigger memory reallocation. Also in an unrelated note, I read that openddir("."); will open the current directory and I have found that it does but for some reason not all of the files in the current directory are in 'stack.ptr' and a . and .. are displayed when I output the contents of 'stack.ptr' to stdout.

Comment: Side note, you can clean up your code a little as `sizeof(char)` will always be 1

Comment: someone would say: a minimal compilable example is needed in order to make us able to try it... apparently there's no reason why if temp is NULL your code should crash (and you catch the case on purpose... don't you?). anyway a debugger may help

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Mike but I perfer to write out char. @ShinTakezou I didn't want to post unnecessary code as I am reasonably sure the problem is within the code snippet above. And you are correct my program did not technically crash. But their is still a problem if realloc() fails to reallocate memory when their is more than enough available.

Comment: the problem may be in there, but it won't manifest so easily to us: we need to imagine it.

Comment: Also, you don't show how you are actually filling `stack.ptr`, how you are incrementing `stack.index`, etc.  Maybe you have a logic bug in that code, that is affecting your management of `stack.ptr`. When you ask questions like this, you need to know everything you are doing.

Comment: On a side note, why not use `std::string` with `std::vector` or other STL container, instead of managing all of the memory manually?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Using `std::string` and `std::vector` could be a tad difficult in C. More inconvenient than manual memory management, in fact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't show us the line that contains the bug. It probably looks like:

```
strcpy(stack.ptr+stack.index, ptr_dirent->d_Name);
```

The problem here is that `strcpy()` copies `strlen() + 1` bytes. You are writing the terminating NUL char beyond the end of your allocated array.

Comment: thank you for your response and yes that would probably cause a problem but I use for(i = stack.index, j = 0; i <= NEW_INDEX; i++, j++) {stack.ptr[i] = ptr_dirent->d_name[j];} to copy the file name to stack.ptr and since NEW_INDEX uses strlen() to find dirent->d_name's length. The terminating NULL should not be a problem. But I am no expert so please correct me if I am wrong.